# Firefox won't open Stack Exchange sites due to "TLS FEATURE MISSING"

Tags: bug, ssl, firefox

I'm running Firefox Quantun, 67.0 (64 bit) on macOS Mojave and it won't load any of the Stack Exchange sites and instead shows a "Secure Connection Failed" page with error code: `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING`

Chrome works fine.

[image]

I believe this might be an issue with StachExchange OCSP response Stapling:

[image]

Comment: Same here (Windows 7 64bit, Firefox 67). At first I thought it was the usual bug with the Avast Web-Shield, but this occurs even with all avast shields turned off. Something changed.

Comment: StackExchange is aware of the issue and is working with their CDN to revoke the bad certificate: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1133787602027286529